# Differences beetween proj4 string and WKT

Tags: proj, well-known-text

What are the differences between proj4 strings and well-known text in terms of the ability to represent a projection, other than for WKT being more human readable?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  As it stands I think your question is too broad because you are asking to have someone provide you with a "beginner's guide".  I recommend you start by reviewing some of the sites found by http://www.google.com/search?q=proj4+wkt+conversion

Comment: Hi, the stuff I found on internet are about how to convert using existing tools and libraries. Here I have to make such a tool. I thought the users here may have a good understanding on the differences between the two types. Anyway I'll try to find more information on the internet.

Comment: If, having done that research, you still need help, then please use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with details of your findings so far, and where you are still stuck.  That way our volunteers do not need to find and suggest things that you have already reviewed and dismissed.

Comment: If you're tasked with re-inventing this particular wheel, then there isn't any way around committing both specifications to memory.  The purpose of open source is to eliminate this duplication of effort (and error, and change dependencies)

Comment: I changed the question. And, nope its not reinventing the wheel. There is a need for a native converter as using existing tools is a depenpendancy that needs to be eliminated to achieve speed and ease of use in the project I am working in.